# When are $L_p(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ Banach

Tags: measure-theory, volume, outer-measure

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $L_p(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be the usual space of all complex/real valued measurable functions $f$ such that
$$\int_X\vert f\vert^p\;d\mu<\infty$$

My question is: when is this space Banach? First of all, does $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ have to be $\sigma$-finite or complete? If it is not, is the $L_p$ still Banach (for any $1\le p\le\infty$)?

Thanks

Comment: Completeness is a function of the metric which is well defined given a measure space. Also, presumably you mean the equivalence classes, in which case the $L^p$ spaces are complete. This is a standard result.

Comment: @copper.hat I believe you did not address his concern on whether the measure space has to be $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Math1000: The $L^p$ spaces are defined on any measure space regardless of $\sigma$-whateverness.

Comment: $L^{p}$ is complete for any positive measure $\mu$. No needed for sigma finiteness or completeness.